# md5 base64 encoder in C++ vs Java

Tags: java, c++, md5

I have a cross-language problem regarding md5 :). 
I have this code in Java:

```
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(someString.getBytes());
byte[] bMac = md.digest();
String anotherString = encoder.encodeBuffer(bMac);
```

This encodes and hashes a string in md5 and base64. A string like "aaa&1" becomes Fv4eRn4R0/mB+uc4j1GGaA==

Now the problem is: how to do this in C++? I'm using openssl/md5.h, but like any other online md5 encoder (after a small google search), it gets a hash like: 
16fe1e467e11d3f981fae7388f518668

Which is in hex it seems. If I try to transform the md5 hash in base64, I get a completely different hash (longer and uglier :) ).

Help!!!

Thank you!

L.E.: I use the MD5 method from openssl/md5.h, as AZI pointed out.

Comment: Please show us the relevant portions of the C++ code you are using.

Comment: I'm guessing that, if the function gives you a hex string, you'll have to convert it to a sequence of bytes `{0x16,0xfe,0x1e,...,0x68}` and then base-64 encode that. I'm not familiar enough with the library to give a proper answer, though.

Comment: `someString.getBytes()` uses the default OS/language encoding; if C++ were not doing that too, it would have been better to explicitly give an encoding: `someString.getBytes("UTF-8")` or `"Windows-1252"`. _Unfortunately it is not unlikely that your code needs to operate on several computers._ For C++ do a search for "Base64Encode".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the C++ code to obtain md5

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, 
               unsigned long n,
               unsigned char *md);
```

example:

```
unsigned char inbuf[] = "aaa&1";
unsigned char outbuf[20];
MD5(inbuf, strlen(inbuf), outbuf);

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", outbuf[i]);
}
```

if Hex of `16fe1e467e11d3f981fae7388f518668` converted to Base64 then [Hex to Base64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)  you will get `Fv4eRn4R0/mB+uc4j1GGaA==`

May refer to [Howto base64 encode with C/C++ and OpenSSL](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/34/howto-base64-encode-with-cc-and-openssl/) to encode this to Base64

Comment: This is exactly the method that I use to get the md5. But how do I convert from the md5 to the base64 format in C++ (exactly as in the link you gave)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use everything Azi and Mike Seymour said... So, to obtain the MD5 hash, you have to use the solution presented by Azi. Then the thing in Java uses something like Mike suggested... it encodes in base64 from binary.

My solution was to look at the code from the link provided by Azi:

http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

And to port it into C++. Fortunately it wasn't that hard to do...
If anyone wants the C++ code, leave a comment.
Thank you all!